Можно ли в ipynb тетрадь встроить невидимый для пользователей Python код?
Соль в том, что надо сделать максимально красивую и удобную для пользователя (аналитика) тетрадь, вариант с веб-хостингом в нашем подразделении компании неприменим. Поэтому танцую вокруг именно ipynb тетради, без установки расширений (крайне желательно), работа в Jupyter Lab. Пока что я пришел к выводу, что в ячейках типа "Code" код всегда показывается, а в "Markdown" ячейках код не выполняется. И единственный вариант - импорт из py файла, то есть распространять все одним файлом не получится, а очень хочется. Есть идеи, как спрятать код?

Заголовки можно сворачивать. Вместе с кодом, который под ними. Можно конечно и развернуть обратно, но как вариант - свернуть вот, чтобы не мешало.

Можно свернуть только ячейки с кодом. В свежих версиях Лаба они сворачиваются из коробки, без расширений. Кликаете на синюю полоску слева и от ячейки с кодом остается только первая строка. Совсем убрать не знаю как.
